# Can a sparkleberry be pollinated by a blueberry?

Tags: blueberries

I've read that the [sparkleberry](https://www.directgardening.com/4313-edibles/3072-sparkleberry#/quantity-1) is a "native shrub is so closely related to the Blueberry, that some experts actually consider it to be one". Does this mean it would do well in a row of blueberries for pollination?

Comment: Since leaving a message when we vote to close is encouraged, I'm just letting you know that in my opinion this is "unclear what you're asking" because it would need a substantial edit with credible information in order for future readers to understand what you mean.

Comment: It was edited, is it answerable now?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone else will know, but the link you got that information from regarding sparkleberry does not say botanically what plant they're talking about, which means its impossible to establish whether its genuinely hardy, genuinely edible, needs more than one for pollination, or will cross pollinate with anything else at all. I suspect (but don't know for sure) what they're actually talking about is a variety of cranberry, given the picture showed it has red berries; both Cranberry and blueberry are Vaccinium varieties (V. oxycoccus or V.macrocarpon for Cranberry, and V.corymbosum for blueberry).